# How do I add a custom field to the login dialog?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, login, plist

When the screensaver has been disturbed, or the computer wakes from sleep, my system asks for a password.  I would like to add to this dialog. Along with username and password, there would be a third field asking for user text input on what they would like to do at the computer. After a successful login, the Automator would take the user input and put it in a stickie note in the corner of the desktop.

This is for productivity purposes, as I always get distracted whenever I go to the computer and after a long time surfing the internet, I forget what I actually logged on for.

I have seen a lot of questions & answers on adding your own text message to the login window, but not any on adding a user input text field.  I have a vague idea of how this might work (which could be totally wrong), but here is what I think:

1. I need to edit the com.apple.loginwindow.plist and add a custom field that asks for user input? (is this possible?)
2. Use Automator to paste the user input into a Stickie.
3. Somehow run a shell script to have the Automator perform this action after every login. (or do I even need this b/c I can do that in the Automator?)

Also not sure: so I need to use AppleScript?

Thanks for any help.  I am on Snow Leopard by the way.

Answer (score 1):

### Probably not.

I would imagine that the lock screen is locked down fairly tight - imagine a piece of malware that did just that - except the Automator action sent the password to a server in Bangladesh.

Comment: Hm, ok, how about if _after_ the login screen has been passed, it would pop up a GUI that would ask for user input? How would I start that?

Comment: @newt I'm pretty sure that's possible - look into something like the Login Items.

Comment: @Undo that would only be after logging in not when giving password to close screensaver